# Populating a Combobox Column in a ListView

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

Incredibly new to WPF here. I'll set the scene:
I've got a ListView with a list of Expenses with something like this:

- Expense Description: Supermarket Shopping
- Expense Date: 2/3/2017
- Expense Amount: $50
- Expense Type: GROCERIES

The expense type is stored in a seperate table in my DB and is linked to the Expense via a foreign key expense_type_id.

I'm trying to get a list of expenses that don't have an Expense Type, and allow the user to set the expense type from a list of options (i.e. the data in the Expense Type table).

To do that I've created a ListView that holds the Expenses without an expense_type_id.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="lvAllocation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="475" Margin="0,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1308" FontSize="16">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Posted" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ex_posted_date}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Trans" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ex_trans_date}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ex_description}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ex_amount}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Expense Type" x:Name ="cmbExpenseType" Width="120">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=IC_NAME }" Width="120" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Above is the WPF that details the List View. The code behind to populate is:

```
    Private Sub SetupAllocationTab()
    'Get list from DB (where there isn't an expense type)
    Dim queryExceptions =
        From expense In dataEntities.expenses
        Where expense.expense_type.ex_type_desc Is Nothing
        Order By expense.ex_posted_date
        Select
            expense.ex_id,
            expense.ex_type_id,
            expense.override_ex_type_id,
            expense.month_id,
            expense.account_id,
            expense.ex_posted_date,
            expense.ex_trans_date,
            expense.ex_description,
            expense.ex_amount,
            expense.ex_deduction,
            expense.notes,
            expense.ex_file_desc,
            expense.insert_datetime,
            expense.insert_user,
            expense.insert_process,
            expense.update_datetime,
            expense.update_user,
            expense.update_process

    'For each item, make an expense object and add it to the ListView
    For Each item In queryExceptions.ToList
        Dim exp = New expense(item.ex_id, item.ex_type_id, item.override_ex_type_id, item.month_id, item.account_id, item.ex_posted_date, item.ex_trans_date, item.ex_description, item.ex_amount,
                                  item.ex_deduction, item.notes, item.ex_file_desc, item.insert_datetime, item.insert_user, item.insert_process, item.update_datetime, item.update_user, item.update_process)
        lvAllocation.Items.Add(exp)
    Next

    'Create list for expense dropdown
    ExceptionTypeDropdown()

End Sub
```

Running off an edmx data model taken from my database.

My question is, how do I populate the ComboBox column with the dat that exists in the table expense_type. This is as far as I've gotten with trying a few things I've been finding out online. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    Private Sub ExceptionTypeDropdown()

    Dim expenseTypes =
    From expense_type In dataEntities.expense_type
    Select expense_type.ex_type_code,
           expense_type.ex_type_desc

    'Add the expense type combo box on the DataGrid


End Sub
```

[Expense List Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuMm6.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Please note my code is more C# than VB.Net, but I guess you can translate this part.*

So, what you need is an independent items source with all possible expense types and a selected value binding into your collection:

In the XAML resources of your control/window:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="expenseTypesSource"/>
```

In code behind initialization:

```
var expenseTypesSource = Resources["expenseTypesSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
expenseTypesSource.Source = expenseTypes; // each item as { ex_type_code, ex_type_desc }
```

The combobox usage:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource expenseTypesSource}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="ex_type_desc"
    SelectedValuePath="ex_type_code"
    SelectedValue="{Binding ex_type_id}"
    Width="120" />
```

With proper usage of the `DataContext`, you can skip the code behind part but I'm not going into details here.